# Structural engineering? single family 2 story home with post tension cable slab concrete beams.1st FL bathrm to add new shower beam cut, add plumbing

Tags: structural, engineering

Structural engineering question, working on a single family 2 story home with post tension cable slab with concrete beams in both directions. Working to add a new shower on a first floor bathroom that requires new plumbing to be setup but area below has 3 foot wide beam. Can or ok to cut into beam with existing plumbing to make new plumbing? Or will this be a problem for foundation integrity in future?

Comment: *"Structural engineering question"* == consult a Licensed Professional Structural Engineer, or "you bet your house" on not doing so. Understand that the consultation may lead to "you can't do that" or "you can't do that there" and you might have to revise your plans to suit the realities of the building staying intact.

Comment: The primary issue here isn't the need for an engineer, but the sheer scope of the question. There's no way we can answer such a ponderous question with the miniscule information we have. Voting to close.

Answer (score 9):

You need to ask your question to an actual structural engineer that can look at your structure design and give you professional guidance. This may very well require a consultation payment contract.

There is no way that anyone here can give you proper advice, especially with the extreme minimal information you have provided.